# What is the difference between GTK and Win32 Native API in C?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C programming. I read about some tutorials and forums about creating GUI application in C. I encountered some terms like GTK, Win32 native API. They say that GTK is one of the library to use in creating GUI application. I also tried the code that create a simple window using Win32 API.  What are the difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: `GTK` is portable(run Linux, MAC, Windows, Android etc..) and it's good for coding. `WIN32 native API` is opposite all quoted before, except run on windows.

Answer (score 3):

**[GTK](http://www.gtk.org/)** is **multi-platform** tool kit for creating graphical user interfaces(GUI).
In short they provide a framework which you can use as an library for developing your UI applications.

**[Win32 API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)** is Microsoft's core set of application programming interfaces (APIs) available in the **Microsoft Windows operating systems**. These are restricted only for windows platform.

The language rules for c/c++ are governed by ISO standards which define what functionality every standard c/c++ implementation has to provide.Note that both of above provide some functionality that is over and above what the standard libraries provide.Basically, they provide you boiler plate framework for easy usage instead of reinventing wheels for your project.

Comment: Thank you to all of you for your response.
That's also the thing i want to know,the compatibility issue in the different platforms..


Is GTK is commonly used in many C applications?
Is it recommended in developement?

Comment: As @Als says, Win32 API is restricted to Windows but that doesn't necessarily mean you shouldn't use it.  If you app is only going to be used on Windows, ones that use the Win32 API look much better than those using the Windows port of GTK.

Comment: You might also be interested in [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) which is portable like GTK but uses the Win32 API internally to give you a better looking GUI.

Answer (score 1):

[Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32) is the "native" API for Microsoft Windows.  You can only run it on Microsoft Windows.

[GTK+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK+) is also a GUI library.  You can run it on multiple different platforms.

[Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt) and [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) are other multi-platform libraries.  Like GTK+, the same GUI can be recompiled to run on multiple different platforms: Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
That's also the thing i want to know,the compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

Gtk+ = cross-platform and very powerfull. more simple than win32. more tools you will have.
win32 = just in windows. standard windows GUI framework.

and DUDE! Gtk+ in windows is a pain in the ass. but for any othe supported platforms I reccomend Gtk+ for a widget toolkit.